# adding a library for iOS app

Tags: ios, c

I am building an iOS app that requires the use of the glm library([link to site](http://glm.g-truc.net)). I don't necessarily want to place the entire library in the app folder every time I want to use it. Is it possible to

A) point xcode to the library folder so it knows where to find the headers

or

B) place the library in the standard iOS library folder.

Im sure this is something developers must do all the time, but Ive been unable to find a simple solution on the web.

Comment: If jailbreaking is an option, I advise you to make a proper shared library out of the source code of the library, that's the cleanest solution.

Comment: Cheers, no Jailbreak is not an option

Comment: Perhaps you should create a template for your projects with the library included.

Comment: Here's a link to help: http://www.iphonedevfaq.com/index.php?title=Xcode_Project_Template